# Stacked column Flash chart counting all values

Tags: oracle, charts, report, oracle-apex

I am building stacked column flash chart on my query. I would like to split values in column for different locations. For argument sake I have 5 ids in location 41, 3 ids in location 21, 8 ids in location 1

```
select 
''  link,
To_Char(ENQUIRED_DATE,'MON-YY') label, 
count(decode(location_id,41,id,0)) "location1",
count(decode(location_id,21,id,0)) "location2",
count(decode(location_id,1,id,0)) "location3"
from  "my_table"
where 
some_conditions = 'Y';
```

as a result of this query Apex is creating stacked column with three separate parts( hurray!), however it instead of having values 5,3 and 8, it returns three regions 16,16,16. ( 16 = 5 +3+8).
So obviously Apex is going through all decode conditions and adding all values.
I am trying to achieve something described in this
[article](http://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/apex-4-charts-dynamically-adding-a-series-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex doesn't appear to be doing anything funky, you'd get the same result running that query through SQL*Plus. When you do:

```
count(decode(location_id,41,id,0)) "location1",
```

.. then the count gets incremented for every row - it doesn't matter which column you include, and the zero is just treated as any fixed value. I think you meant to use `sum`:

```
sum(decode(location_id,41,1,0)) "location1",
```

Here each row is assigned either zero or one, and summing those gives you the number that got one, which is the number that had the specified `id` value.

Personally I'd generally use `case`over `decode`, but the result is the same:

```
sum(case when location_id = 41 then 1 else 0 end) "location1",
```